# Unrecognized expression when using special ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in my jQuery Mobile 1.2 project. It was working fine until I upgraded from jQuery 1.7.2 to jQuery 1.8.3.

```
<input type="text" id="a['val']" name="a['val']" />
```

When the page is loaded, it throws

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='a['val']']`

and the page refuse to load. Although there's no label in my code, the error thrown is asking for a label. This problem only occurs specifically in jQuery 1.8 and it's working fine for 1.9 and versions prior to 1.8.

Here's the [Fiddle with problem on 1.8.3 + JQM 1.2](http://jsfiddle.net/calebc/YKGaM/1/)

Here's the [Fiddle without problem on 1.9.1 + JQM 1.2](http://jsfiddle.net/calebc/LPNG7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug or feature in jQuery 1.8 + jqm 1.2, it occurs when you have an id containing '

JQuery can't transfer it to a selector of the label correctly and throw the error, you can modify the id to `"a[val]"` or `'a["val"]'`, then it's ok.

```
<input type="text" id='a["val"]' name="a['val']" />
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKGaM/2/)

Comment: Yes. I have tested the double quote will work. But that still did not explain the mystery label which thrown.

Comment: The label comes from jqm, jqm always try to find a label with input. in document of jqm. You will see that input tag should be attached with a label tag, if you don't want to display it ,add a class . See http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/forms/textinputs/